# CRC function. Converting C to C#

Tags: c#, c, crc

I need to convert these C functions to C#. Just wanted to double check if I've done it right. Thanks!

**C Code:**

```
unsigned short Crc;

unsigned short update_crc(unsigned short crc, char c) {
    char i;

    crc ^= (unsigned short)c<<8;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if (crc & 0x8000) crc = (crc<<1)^0x1021;
        else crc <<=1;
    }
    return crc;
}


void exampleCRC(void){

 #define INITIAL_CRC 0xffff

unsigned short Crc = INITIAL_CRC;
record_t record;

    for (byteCount=0; byteCount<sizeof(record_t); byteCount++) {
        Crc = update_crc(Crc, record[byteCount] );
    }
}
```

**C# Code:**

```
ushort UpdateCrc(ref ushort crc, byte b)
{
    crc ^= (ushort)(b << 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if ((crc & 0x8000) > 0)
            crc = (ushort)((crc << 1) ^ 0x1021);
        else
            crc <<= 1;
    }

    return crc;
}

ushort CalcCrc(byte[] data)
{
    ushort crc = 0xFFFF;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        crc = UpdateCrc(ref crc, data[i]);

    return crc;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems fine to me, except you really don't need a `ref` parameter for `UpdateCrc` since you're returning the modified value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running tests on a variety of different values?

Also maybe make them `static` functions (if that wasn't your plan already) since they don't seem to need to access any object state.